# выполнение строки в .bat файл. child_process - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bat

Есть samp.bat файл. Он запускается, работает и т.д. Но при запуске не через NodeJS в нем можно писать заранее прописанные команды по типу "stop" "start" "restart". Но я не нашел способа как можно выполнять команды внутри NodeJS. Как можно выполнять эти команды через NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Через [cp.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) или [cp.execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) можно запустить любую команду операционной системы. А через [cp.kill](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) остановить.

А из bat можно запустить строку яваскрипта используя `node -e "console.log(123)"`.

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду что вот уже приложение запущено и оно запускает сторонний bat файл который лежит рядом с server.js. И далее допустим каждые 5 секунд надо выполнять команду  "start" которая отправляется в консоль этого bat файла